# EGL No suitable configuration found that matches the minimum critera

Tags: android, configuration, unity-game-engine, android-virtual-device, egl

I am building a Unity project as an APK and attempting to run it on a Galaxy Nexus AVD. It always crashes immediately after being opened without displaying anything. A quick look at logcat shows the error:

> [EGL] No suitable configuration found that matches the minimum
>   critera.

I have been searching for a solution. One site recommended I check "Use 32-bit display buffer" in Player Settings for my Unity project before exporting it, but that didn't make any difference. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check "Use host GPU" in AVD settings.

That works in my case, anyway.